# How to upload file with editMessageMedia via telegram bot?

Tags: json, curl, bots, telegram

Editing message text with

```
curl "https://api.telegram.org/bot123/editMessageText?chat_id=-123123&message_id=123123123&text"=BLAH""
```

is working

Now I want to edit another message with attached file (replace file )

```
curl -d media='{"type": "document", "media": "@/home/user/file.mp3"}' "https://api.telegram.org/bot123/editMessageMedia?
chat_id=-123123&message_id=123123124
```

And get error `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: invalid file HTTP URL specified: URL host is empty"}`

How to proprely attach local file here
?

Answer (score 0):

that is

```
curl -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
    -F "media={\"type\":\"animation\", \"media\":\"attach://animation\"};type=application/json" \
    -F chat_id=123456 \
    -F message_id=123 \
    -F animation=@/home/test/area.mp4 \
    https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/editMessageMedia
```

you should define TOKEN and use correct chat_id and message_id to edit message.

tested for me and works in project